# How can I optimize a query that returns a lot of records, then order by a date field and return only the latest one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following doubt about the possible optimization of this query (defined on a **MySql** database):

```
SELECT MCPS.id AS series_id,
        MD_CD.market_details_id AS market_id,
        MD_CD.commodity_details_id AS commodity_id,
        MD.market_name AS market_name,
        MCPS.price_date AS price_date,
        MCPS.avg_price AS avg_price,
        CU.ISO_4217_cod AS currency, 
        MU.unit_name AS measure_unit, 
        CD.commodity_name_en,
        CN.commodity_name 
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series AS MCPS
INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU ON MCPS.measure_unit_id = MU.id
INNER JOIN Currency AS CU ON MCPS.currency_id = CU.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD ON MCPS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD ON MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id
INNER JOIN CommodityDetails AS CD ON MD_CD.commodity_details_id = CD.id
INNER JOIN CommodityName AS CN ON CD.id = CN.commodity_details_id
INNER JOIN Languages AS LN ON CN.language_id  = LN.id
WHERE MD.id = 4
AND CD.id = 4 
AND LN.id=1
ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

It contains a lot of join only because the information in the tables are very normalized.

This query returns the information related the last price of a commodity (**AND CD.id = 4**) in a specific market (**WHERE MD.id = 4).

So I am first retrieving the list of all prices of a specific commodity in a specific market (that can be a lot of records) and then I do:

```
ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

I think that maybe this way can be computationally expensive because the first part of the query (the entire query except the last **ORDER BY** statment will retrieve a lot of records that then have to be ordered.

Is it a problem? Eventually what could be a smart strategy to optimize this query? (I have no idea...)

Comment: There's not much to do in the way the query is written. It boils down to using proper indexes. Post the result of `EXPLAIN <your_query>;`

Comment: @fancyPants ehhh my doubt is: can this query to be written in a better way?

Comment: The query looks fine, how long does it take to run?

Comment: @AndreaNobili There's nothing to write better. There's nothing complicated in this query. It's straight forward. You just join some tables and read the data. That's it. Nothing to rewrite here.

Comment: If a query runs for too long, the problem more often than not lies in the data structure itself, not in the query. Just as @fancyPants suggests, you should make sure to use proper indexes, it will help to make a query run much faster than any "optimization" on the query itself could ever achieve.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. In particular give DDL & EXPLAIN output. But be complete. PS What is quite likely & hasn't been mentioned is that you are missing join conditions so that you are returning pre-sort many more rows than reasonable given what the tables mean.

Comment: Sorry, but snowflake schemas are not easy to optimize.  However, if any of those are many-to-many tables, heed the advice [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table); that may improve performance some.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621414/optimizing-a-query-returning-a-lot-of-records-a-way-to-avoid-hundreds-of-join ?

Answer (score 0):

Sanity check... are `MD_CD.commodity_details_id` and `CN.commodity_details_id` different?  Or is it a typo?

Get rid of

```
INNER JOIN Languages AS LN ON CN.language_id  = LN.id
 ...
AND LN.id=1
```

Instead, simply have `AND CN.language_id = 1`

Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` whenever you try a formulation.

It seems that most things are centered around `commodity_details_id = 4`.  So say `AND MD_CD.commodity_details_id = 4`, not `MD.id = 4` and `CD.id = 4`.

Now, let's try to reformulate it for a little bit of efficiency.  Let's start with the main filter -- `AND MD_CD.commodity_details_id = 4`, so let's say  `FROM MD_CD  JOIN ...`.  Then add `JOINs` until we can get to `MCPS`.price_date`so we can work on`ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT very-few-columns
    FROM MD_CD
    JOIN ...  (the minimal set of tables)
    JOIN MCPS ON ...
    WHERE MD_CD.commodity_details_id = 4
    ORDER BY MCPS.price_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Before going further, debug that above to make sure it is providing the correct one row.

To finish out the query, there are two approaches:

Plan A:  Use that is a 'derived table' and add more JOINs on:

```
SELECT lots-of-stuff
    FROM ( the above query ) AS x
    JOIN the rest of the tables
```

Plan B:  Use subqueries in the SELECT for the missing columns:

```
SELECT some stuff,
       ( SELECT commodity_name_en FROM CN
             WHERE commodity_details_id = CD.id ) AS commodity_name_en,
       etc
    FROM ... (as above)
```

(And heed my advice on many-to-many schema in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table )