# Optimizing a query returning a lot of records, a way to avoid hundreds of join. Is it a smart solution?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, rdbms

I am not so int SQL and I have the following doubt about how to optimize a query. I am using **MySql**

I have this DB schema:

[image]

And this is the query that returns the last price (the last date into the **Market_Commodity_Price_Series** table) of a specific commodity into a specific market.

It contains a lot of join to retrieve all the related information:

```
SELECT MCPS.id AS series_id,
        MD_CD.market_details_id AS market_id,
        MD_CD.commodity_details_id AS commodity_id,
        MD.market_name AS market_name,
        MCPS.price_date AS price_date,
        MCPS.avg_price AS avg_price,
        CU.ISO_4217_cod AS currency, 
        MU.unit_name AS measure_unit, 
        CD.commodity_name_en,
        CN.commodity_name 
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series AS MCPS
INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU ON MCPS.measure_unit_id = MU.id
INNER JOIN Currency AS CU ON MCPS.currency_id = CU.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD ON MCPS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id
INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD ON MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id
INNER JOIN CommodityDetails AS CD ON MD_CD.commodity_details_id = CD.id
INNER JOIN CommodityName AS CN ON CD.id = CN.commodity_details_id
INNER JOIN Languages AS LN ON CN.language_id  = LN.id
WHERE MD.id = 4
AND CD.id = 4 
AND LN.id=1
ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

My doubt is: using the previous query I am extracting all the records related to a specific commodity into a specific market from the **Market_Commodity_Price_Series** table, do a lot of join, ordinating these records based on the **price_date** field and limiting to the last one.

I think that it could be expansive because I can have a lot of records (because the **Market_Commodity_Price_Series** table contains daily information).

This query works but I think that can be done in a smarter way.

So I thought that I can do something like this:

1) Select the record related to the last price of a specific commodity into a specific market using a query like this:

```
SELECT measure_unit_id, 
        currency_id, 
        market_commodity_details_id, 
        MAX(price_date) price_date
FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series  AS MCPS 
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD ON MCPS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id
WHERE MD_CD.market_details_id = 4
AND MD_CD.commodity_details_id = 4
GROUP BY measure_unit_id, currency_id, market_commodity_details_id
```

that returns the single record related to this information:

```
measure_unit_id      currency_id          market_commodity_details_id price_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    2                    24                          05/10/2017
```

Use this output like a table (I don't know the exact name, maybe view, is it?) and join this "table" to the other required information that are into the **MeasureUnit, Currency, MarketDetails, CommodityDetails, CommodityName and Languages** tables.

I think that it could be better because in this way I am using the **MAX(price_date) price_date** to extract only the record related to the latest price into the **Market_Commodity_Price_Series** instead obtain all the records, ordering and limiting to the latest one.

Furthermore most onf the **JOIN** operation are doing o the single record returned by the previous query and not on all the records returned by the first version of my query (potentially they could be hundreds or thousands).

Could be a smart solution?

If yes...what is the correct syntax to join the output of this query (considering it as a table) with the other tables?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605178/how-can-i-optimize-a-query-that-returns-a-lot-of-records-then-order-by-a-date-f ?

Comment: You have 10k rep. Where is your [mcve]? How is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46605178/3404097?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done a reasonably good job of writing an efficient query.

You didn't use `SELECT *`, which can mess up performance in a query with lots of joins, because it generates bloated and redundant intermediate result sets. But your intermediate result set -- the one you apply `ORDER BY` to -- is not bloated.

Your `WHERE col = val` clauses mostly mention primary keys of tables (I guess). That's good.

Your big table `Market_Commodity_Price_Series` could maybe use a [compound covering index](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727). Similarly, some other tables may need that kind of index.  But that should be the topic of another question.

Your proposed optimization -- ordering an intermediate result set consisting mostly of `id` values -- would help a lot if you were doing `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` and using the `LIMIT` function to discard most of your results.  But you are not doing that.

Without knowing more about your data, it's hard to offer a crisp opinion. But, if it were me I'd use your first query. I'd keep an eye on it as you go into production (and on other complex queries). When (not if) performance starts to deteriorate, then you can do `EXPLAIN` and figure out the best way to index your tables. You've done a good job of writing a query that will get your application up and running. Go with it!

Comment: So do you think that the first original query should be not so bad?

Comment: Ok a last question for you. Considering my first query do you think that the WHERE clause that are applied on the MarketDetails an on the CommodityDetails tables are applied before the JOIN? (So it should means that the joins are applied of a single row for both table)

Comment: Yes, recent versions of MySQL do a good job of reducing the cardinality of their search spaces by applying filters early.

Comment: @AndreaNobili If you googled the official documentation site for 'optimization' & specifically with 'where' and/or 'join' you would answer that for youself. So when people don't take such simple actions in their own behalf other peoples' time is wasted. Ditto re your lack of [mcve]. This is why the downvote arrow mouseover text talks about lack of research.

Answer (score 3):

`JOIN`s -- particularly on primary keys -- are not necessarily expensive.  It looks like your joins are following the data model.

I wouldn't start optimizing the query without understanding its performance characteristics.  How long does it take to run?  How many records are being sorted to get the most recent?

Your `WHERE` clause appears to be limiting the data considerably.  You can also set up an index to help with the `WHERE` clause clause -- however, because the fields come from different tables, it can be tricky to use indexes or all of them.

You have a complicated data model that is a bit difficult to follow. It seems possible that you are getting a Cartesian product due to multiple n-m relationships.  If so, that can have a big impact on performance, and pre-aggregating the data along each dimension is the way to go.

However, I wouldn't start optimizing the query without understanding how the current one behaves.

Comment: So...I still don't know if I will have performance problem in the future because at this time I have few mocked data into my DB. I am not so into database and I have a doubt about your assertion: "Your WHERE clause appears to be limiting the data considerably". Do you mean that this where clause are applied before all the join? (So these joins are few) or what?

Comment: @AndreaNobili . . . The database does what it can to be efficient.

Comment: @AndreaNobili You have misconceptions about query execution, research it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach is to make a separate Read Model Table it comes from [CQRS approach](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) with containing all necessary attributes just for select and no any joins but you will need to update the Read Model table each time some other tables changes
one more options is to create a [View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)

Comment: This used to be called just "data marts".